# Python: Inverse Replace Function

Tags: python, replace

I have no idea about how I explain this, but here goes...

```
>>> x = 'qwertyHelloWorldasdfg'
>>> x = inversereplace(x, 'HelloWorld', 'a')
>>> print x  
aaaaaaHelloWorldaaaaaa  

>>> y = 'qwertyHelloWorld'
>>> y = inversereplace(y, 'qwerty', '')
>>> print y
qwerty
```

In the function above, it replaces everything in x that is not **Not** the 2nd argument with the 3rd Argument.
How would I go about doing this?
If there is already a function that does this then please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
~DragonXDoom

Comment: have you got a real-world use-case for this?  I can't get over the suspicion that there must be a better way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
def inversereplace(text, word, repl):
    parts = text.split(word)
    return word.join(repl*len(x) for x in parts)
```

Comment: D'oh, beat me to it!  Plus, used cool list-comprehension.  Alack-a-day, powned...

Answer (score 1):

```
def inversereplace(s, p, q):
   s = s.split(p)
   s = map(lambda x: q * len(x), s)
   return p.join(s)
```

Comment: What, you use `map` and `lambda`, but your `s` is not immutable? :)

Comment: If I were to do it again now (30 months later), I might write: `def inversereplace(s, p, q): return p.join( map(lambda x: q * len(x), s.split(p))`